# Ruby: How to map a model on XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri, ruby-on-rails-6

In Ruby-on-Rails 6.0, I want to create a Resource named services, with the model, view and controller.

Each service has an ID, a Name, a Type and an ImageIndex

But I want the model maps on XML (see below) instead of ActiveRecord.
And I want that the actions (index, show, new, edit and destroy) modify the XML itself.

My first attemp has been to add code into the controller to parse the XML, as follow:

```
  def index
    @services = []

    f = File.open("xml/eidos/LeftTree/Services.xml")
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
    f.close
    root = doc.root
    tags = root.xpath("Tag")

    tags.each do |tag|
      @service = Service.new
      @service.node_name = tag.xpath("NodeName").text
      @service.text = tag.xpath("Text").text
      @service.image_index = tag.xpath("ImageIndex").text
      @services << @service
    end

    @services 
  end
```

This succeded and return me the full instance list.
I'm doing the same for `def Show` (note that I don't need to edit or delete XML)

**The intermediate question now is:**

How can I manage the children of the main Tag element?

I should create at least two other resources: a `request` and a `choice` (and much more, based on the content of the `type` element), and my approach looks not clean.

**And the final question is:**

This is why I would like to find/build an approach like an ActiveRecord replacement, where I can list the attributes and the relationships of my resources.

Any suggestion in this direction?

The sample XML looks like the following:

```
<Services>
  <Tag>
    <ID>X401ED7DA027C</ID>
    <Name>Accertamento Ici Con Adesione</Name>
    <Type>Service</Type>
    <ImageIndex>0</ImageIndex>
  </Tag>
  <Tag>
    <ID>X3F9BEB550223</ID>
    <Name>Cambio di abitazione</Name>
    <Type>Service</Type>
    <ImageIndex>0</ImageIndex>
    <Tag>
      <ID>X3F9BEB550223/X400E4CBA032E</ID>
      <Name>Richiesta Di Cambio Di Abitazione</Name>
      <Type>Request</Type>
      <ImageIndex>1</ImageIndex>
      <Tag>
        <ID>X3F9BEB550223/X400E4CBA032E/X40091B660349_X3FFF3E980118</ID>
        <Name>Allegato</Name>
        <Type>Choice</Type>
        <Multiplicity>
          <MinOccurrence>0</MinOccurrence>
          <MaxOccurrence>*</MaxOccurrence>
        </Multiplicity>
        <Required>False</Required>
        <ImageIndex>5</ImageIndex>
        <IDRole>X40091B660349</IDRole>
        <NameSpace>OggettiCondivisi</NameSpace>
      </Tag>
    </Tag>
  </Tag>
</Services>
```

Comment: Why is this a Nokogiri question? I see no attempt to use Nokogiri for parsing or generation.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord doesn't have built-in support for flat-file databases. If you want to use ActiveRecord I'd suggest you use one of the supported databases and import/export from and to XML.

Comment: I already have a large set of XML files, and I don't want to use ActiveRecord, but only manage the XML files in a way analogous to the ActiveRecord one

Answer (score 0):

This answer is really just putting makeup on a pig. As there are no benefits at all to making your own XML based object persistence (theres a reason nobody does it) and it will just take time that you could have put to better use. Just use Mongoid or some other NoSQL db if the data does not adhere to a strict schema.

The first step is to move the importation into the model and make it suck less:

```
class Service
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :node_name, String
  attribute :text, String
  attribute :image_index, String

  def self.import(fn = "xml/eidos/LeftTree/Services.xml")
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(fn))
    tags = doc.root.xpath("Tag")
    tags.map do |tag|
      Service.new(
        node_name: tag.xpath("NodeName").text,
        text: tag.xpath("Text").text,
        image_index: tag.xpath("ImageIndex").text
      )
    end
  end
end
```

This will let you skinny the controller action down to just:

```
def index
  @services = Service.import
end
```

`#each` should only be used if you only care about the side effects of the loop and not the return value. For example:

```
@users.each do |u|
  u.send_welcome_email!
end
```

For EVERYTHING else use `#map` or the other methods from enumerable such as `#collect`, `#reject`...

You're also reassigning the instance variable `@service` for every iteration of the loop. Learn the difference between instance variables and local variables. And be a bit more sparse with the amount of local variables you're assigning. You don't need to assign everything to a variable - especially not if your just using it once.

The reason you want to do the import in the model (or even a separate service object) is that controllers are hard to test. They have a large amount of dependencies and the only good way to really test them is indirectly through HTTP requests. Controllers are the glue code that ties everything together in Rails - don't bloat them.

A model on the other hand is much easier to test as you can just call `Service.import` and write assertions about the results.

> And I want that the actions (index, show, new, edit and destroy) modify the >XML itself.

Have fun with that. You would need to use Nokogiri to load and modify the document tree. After *n* number of hours you will have built something that basically does what a DB does but worse in every way since it does not scale at all.

> This is why I would like to find/build an approach like an
>   ActiveRecord replacement, where I can list the attributes and the
>   relationships of my resources.

Again - total waste of time. You can just create something with `ActiveModel::Model` that acts like an associations do in ActiveRecord. But why?

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163082/using-xml-as-data-storage

Comment: Thank you Max for your suggestions. BTW, the only reason I'm using XML and not a DB, is that I have thousands of XML files, and those files are regenerated by a third party application I cannot modify.

Moreover, how to parse and manage deep recursive 'has_many'?

And how to manage a monster attribute like this:

```
<xs:xsd xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:simpleType name="Testo">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:String">
   <xs:pattern value="\S[\S|\s]*"/>

Comment: Your only chance at sanity is probably to import the XML and normalize it to a data model for your application eg a database. And then setup XML views or some sort of serializer that exports the data back out when needed.